# Access to the value of an argument to a function invocation in LLVM

Tags: c++11, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api, llvm-4.0

In my LLVM IR, I have a number of function invocations that look like this:

```
%2 = invoke i16 @"_ZN41_$LT$std..sync..mpsc..Sender$LT$T$GT$$GT$4send17h3c94bf47bc6c3500E"(%"std::sync::mpsc::Sender<weather::Weather>"* dereferenceable(16) %weather_sender, i8 %1)
      to label %bb4 unwind label %cleanup, !dbg !717
```

I want to statically analyze them in order to find the value for the last argument, `%_6`.
Is there a way to get its value? I tried to access the argument directly but this just gives me the instruction where the argument is loaded/allocated. So this:

```
if (InvokeInst* ii = dyn_cast<InvokeInst>(&instr)) {
    Value* v = ii->getArgOperand(ii->getNumArgOperands() - 1);
    v->dump();
}
```

just gives me `%1 = load i8, i8* %_5, !dbg !717`, the load instruction that gives me

Comment: Instructions produce values.  The value returned by the load would be passed in as the last argument to the function call.

Comment: I should have added that this is part of a static analysis I'm conducting on the code, sorry.

Comment: Being static analysis, all that LLVM can say is that this instruction will produce the value.  I am not not sure what other value you want.

Comment: The values used as arguments are known during compile-time. `%1` for instance is _1_.
So I'll have to move back up through the instructions until I find the associated `store` instruction that stores the value that will be loaded and passed as argument later on?

Comment: Yes, depending on optimizations, the compiler might be able to reuse the value from the store without loading it again.  Otherwise, you can try traversing the instructions to find a store that has the same address calculations as the load.